# Working with 'tr' in bash script

Tags: bash

How can I work with `tr '[a-z]' '[A-Z]'` in Bash script?

I want save `$1` to a text file using `tr '[a-z]' '[A-Z]'` and print to console.

How can I do this?

```
#!/bin/bash  
echo $1 | tr '[a-z]' '[A-Z]'
exit 0
```

is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the command [tee](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?tee).

Example :

```
echo "AbC" | tr '[a-z]' '[A-Z]' | tee output.txt
```

It will print `ABC`  in the terminal and in a file (output.txt)

Answer (score 2):

With Bash≥4, you don't need to `tr` to convert to upper case since you can use parameter expansions: `${var^^}` will expand to the uppercase expansion of `var`.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Convert first argument to upper case and save in variable upper1
upper1=${1^^}

# print to console:
printf '%s\n' "$upper1"

# and save to file
printf > file.txt '%s\n' "$upper1"
```

All this is done in pure Bash with no external tools. Also, there are no pipes and subshells needed.